# Add nth level cms page to top menu using observer magento 1.9

Tags: magento, drop-down-menu, submenu, magento-1.9

I m trying to add cms page to topnavigation but it display only two level i want to make it like magento default rendering menu.i have tried following code to add cms page to top navigation but if there is sub menu of parent then how can i add to that child to parent using recursion method.

```
public function addItemsToTopmenuItems($observer)
{
 $menu = $observer->getMenu();
$tree = $menu->getTree();

$node = new Varien_Data_Tree_Node(array(
        'name'   => 'Categories',
        'id'     => 'categories',
        'url'    => Mage::getUrl(), // point somewhere
), 'id', $tree, $menu);

$menu->addChild($node);

// Children menu items
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
          ->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1)
          ->addFieldToFilter('identifier',array(array('nin'=>array('no-route','enable-cookies'))));

foreach ($collection as $category) {
    $tree = $node->getTree();
    $data = array(
        'name'   => $category->getTitle(),
        'id'     => 'category-node-'.$category->getId(),
        'url'    => Mage::getUrl($category->getIdentifier()),
    );

    $subNode = new Varien_Data_Tree_Node($data, 'id', $tree, $node);
    $node->addChild($subNode);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was in your situation this week, and finally I achieved the solution using tree nodes. Here is the solution:

```
public function addItemsToTopmenuItems($observer)
{
        /** @var Varien_Data_Tree_Node */
        $menu = $observer->getMenu();
        /** @var  Varien_Data_Tree*/
        $tree = $menu->getTree();

        /** @var Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection */
        $menuCollection = $menu->getChildren();

        /** @var array of Varien_Data_Tree_Node*/
        $nodes = $menuCollection->getNodes();


        //Get "inlcude in navigation menu" parent CMS pages
        $collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('include_in_nav',true)
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_active',true)
            ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', array(array('null' => true), array('eq' => 0)))
            ->setOrder('sort_order');


        $cmsHelper=Mage::helper('cms/page');

        foreach ($collection as $item) {

            $node = new Varien_Data_Tree_Node(array(
                'name'   => $item->getData('title'),
                'id'     => $item->getData('identifier'),
                'url'    => $cmsHelper->getPageUrl($item->getData('page_id')), // point somewhere
            ), 'id', $tree, $menu);


            $menu->addChild($node);

            $parent_id = $item->getData('page_id');
            $this->getAllChilds($node,$parent_id);
        }
    }
```

And getAllChilds function:

```
private function getAllChilds($node,$parent, $defaultNode = null){
    $cmsHelper=Mage::helper('cms/page');

    $pages = Mage::getModel('cms/page')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToSelect('title')
        ->addFieldToSelect('page_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('identifier')
        ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $parent)
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->load();

    $tree = $node->getTree();

    if(count($pages) > 0) {
        foreach ($pages as $item){
            $data = array(
                'name' => $item->getData('title'),
                'id' => $item->getData('identifier'),
                'url' => $cmsHelper->getPageUrl($item->getData('page_id')),
            );

            $subNode = new Varien_Data_Tree_Node($data, 'id', $tree, $node);
            $node->addChild($subNode);

            $node = $this->getAllChilds($subNode,$item->getData('page_id'), $node);
        }
        $node = $this->getAllChilds($subNode,$item->getData('page_id'));
    }

    $childNode = $node;
    if($defaultNode !== null)
        $childNode = $defaultNode;

    return $childNode;
}
```

But you need some extra data in cms tables, like as 'parent_id' field. This is my mysql4-install-0.1.0.php file:

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$table = $installer->getTable('cms/page');

$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($table,'parent_id',array(
    'type'      =>Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
    'comment'   => 'Parent CMS Page'
));

$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($table,'include_in_nav',
    array(
        'type'      =>Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_BOOLEAN,
        'comment'   => 'Include in navigation menu'
    ));

$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($table,'position',
    array(
        'type'      =>Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        'comment'   => 'Position from navigation (category) menu. 1=left; 2=right'
    )); //1: left; 2: right

$installer->endSetup();
```

And finally you need to add these fields to the CMS / Pages backend menu: https://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-custom-attribute-to-a-cms-page/

Best regards!